# O que "re:" e "im:" significam no Rust?

Tags: struct, sintaxe, rust

Quero saber oque `re` e `im` significam/fazem

```
let mut z = Complex { re: 0.0, im: 0,0 };
```

Estou aprendendo Rust pelo livro Programming Rust e isso de `re:` e `im:` já deve ter aparecido antes, mas só agora me dei ao trabalho de pesquisar.

O que achei antes de chegar aqui foi que `im:` é uma maneira para criar estruturas imutáveis de código (tradução livre de: *immutable data structures*), mas nada sobre o `re`, que chuto que pode ser reutilizável.

Outra coisa que achei do `im:` também foi na documentação do Rust onde dizia que era uma *crate*, então não tenho certeza se é outra coisa completamente diferente (essa é a única dependência listada no `Cargo.toml "num = "0.1.27"`")

Comment: Já estudou números complexos antes? Ele é composto por uma parte real (Re) e uma parte imaginária (Im).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rust permite que você inicialize um objeto com uma forma de literal. Essa forma é composta pelo nome do tipo, de chaves que indicarão o início e fim desse literal, como se fosse as aspas de uma *string*, e depois você colocará os membros que deseja inicializar os dados do objeto.

Rust não tem construtor como outras linguagens, ele pode ter funções simples que servem como construtores, mas a forma mais utilizada é a inicialização pura e simples desta forma de literal.

Então é parecido com uma chamada de função com argumentos nomeados, só que o que está fazendo é usar os nomes dos membros da `struct` e os seus valores. Então o que está antes do `:` é o nome do membro e o o que está depois do `:` é o valor que será atribuído a esse membro.

Neste exemplo que é um tipo `Complex`, `re` é a parte real do número e `im` é a parte imaginária. Nada tem a ver com o que especulou na pergunta, é muito mais simples que isto. Esta informação tem a ver com o tipo de dados ali, o `Complex` e não com regras da linguagem. A linguagem só determina a sintaxe deste inicializador de objetos.

Outro exemplo hipotético:

```
let joao = Funcionario { nome : "João", salario : 1000 };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Field.rs).

Entendeu? São apenas [membros da `struct`](https://docs.rs/num-complex/0.1.42/num_complex/struct.Complex.html), e diga-se de passagem nomes mal escolhidos, na verdade tem cara de C e não de Rust que costuma abreviar muito.

Answer (score 7):

Isso não tem relação alguma com imutável ou reutilizável.

Provavelmente em algum momento do livro foi definida uma estrutura semelhante a:

```
struct Complex {
    re: f64,
    im: f64
}
```

Que representa um [número complexo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_complexo). `re` representa a parte real, enquanto `im` representa a parte imaginária.

Ao fazer:

```
let mut z = Complex { re: 0.0, im: 0.0 };
```

Você basicamente está criando um objeto `z`, que segue a estrutura `Complex`, possuindo o valor zero tanto na parte real quanto na parte imaginária.

Você pode ler mais sobre *struct* em [Using Structs to Structure Related Data](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-00-structs.html).

Comment: Acho que entendi, obrigado.